# Using regex to separate individual words?

Tags: java, c#, regex, string, split

I have the following line to split a sentence into words and store it into an array based on white spaces: `string[] s = Regex.Split(input, @"\s+");`

The problem is at the end of the sentence, it also picks up the period. For example: `C# is cool.`

The code would store:

1. `C#`
2. `is`
3. `cool.`

**The question is:** How do I get it not to pick up the period ?

Comment: You will have to filter for other characters in addition to `\s`.

Comment: Can you just use string[] s = input.replace(".","").split(" ") ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a character class `[]` to add in the dot `.` or other characters that you need to split on.

```
string[] s = Regex.Split(input, @"[\s.]+");
```

See [`Demo`](http://ideone.com/b9j38z)

Answer (score 3):

You can add dot (and other punctuation marks as needed) to the regular expression, like this:

```
string[] s = Regex.Split(input, @"(\s|[.;,])+");
```

Comment: I don't see why you don't just use `[\s.;,]+`

Comment: @HamZa True, that would be identical. This is my personal preference to put special character classes outside square brackets, because I think it is slightly more readable. I agree that this is highly subjective, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] s = Regex.Split(input, @"[^\w#]+");
```

You may need to add more characters to set `[^\w#]`, so it will work for you based on your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

Use the non-word character pattern: `\W`

```
string[] s = Regex.Split(input, @"\W+");
```

Comment: This will split on the `#` also

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Regex.Matches as alternative for your requirement...

```
string[] outputMessage = Regex.Matches(inputMessage, @"\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToArray();
```

Good Luck!